# Ciphertext XOR error

Tags: python

I am trying to take a text file and do some XOR's of ciphertexts. When I run the script, I am getting the below error from XORing ciphertext 1 with the others ciphertexts.  Can someone help me here?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./letters.py", line 45, in <module>
    print xorTwoLists(c[0],c[x], lenTarget)
  File "./letters.py", line 22, in xorTwoLists
    xorValue = int(l1[x],16)  ^  int(l2[x],16)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

def splitIntoHexBytes (s) :
   l = []
   for x  in range(0, len(s)/2) :
      y = x*2
      hexStr = '0x'+ s[y:(y+2)]
      l.append( hexStr )
   return l


def makeLen4string(s) :
   if len(s) < 4  :  
      return  s[0:2] + '0' + s[2]
   else :
      return  s


def  xorTwoLists(l1, l2, length) :
   resultList = []
   for x in range(length) :
      xorValue = int(l1[x],16)  ^  int(l2[x],16)
      hexXorValue = hex(xorValue)
      hexString = makeLen4string(hexXorValue)
      resultList.append(hexString)
   return resultList



infile = open('ctexts.txt', 'r')
ciphertexts = infile.readlines()
infile.close()
target = splitIntoHexBytes(ciphertexts[0])

c=[]
for x in range( len(ciphertexts)-1 ) :
   c.append(splitIntoHexBytes(ciphertexts[x+1]) )


lenTarget = len(target)

# Check the first ciphertext for blanks
print "the folllowing is the output of XORing ciphertext 1 with the others ciphertexts :"
for x in range(1, len(c) ):
  print xorTwoLists(c[0],c[x], lenTarget)
print
print "the folllowing is the output of XORing ciphertext 1 with the target :"
print xorTwoLists(c[0],target, lenTarget)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with XORing. Make sure the lists you're passing are of the same length and the length itself is calculated correctly.

Comment: Your error is `IndexError: list index out of range`. In `xorTwoLists` you are passing two lists, `l1` and `l2`. You need to make sure `length` is no longer than the minimum length of the two. You could put `length = min(len(l1)-1, len(l2)-1, length)` on the first line of the function to provide some validation.

Comment: one last thing. my output list is very large. i have about 15 lists and each list has about 25 entries. Is there a way that i can format the output so each entry appears under the corresponding one in the other lists ? At the moment, they are all over the place

Answer (score 0):

If you want to XOR two lists of integers then try the following:

```
def xorTwoLists(l1, l2):
    xorBytes = lambda (x, y): x ^ y # lambda function to XOR individual bytes
    return map(xorBytes, zip(l1, l2))  # zip the two lists then apply xorBytes to the byte tuples
```

And for inputs:

```
c1 = [224, 22, 149, 10, 65, 125, 77, 58]
c2 = [11, 162, 186, 182, 69, 175, 52, 75, 13, 119, 8, 176, 0, 39, 205, 74]
```

You will get the XOR of the two lists up to the length of the smaller list.
In this case:

```
>>> xorTwoLists(c1, c2)
[235, 180, 47, 188, 4, 210, 121, 113]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I copied and pasted it and seems okay for me. Can you please be more precise on the error?